# Capacitor on transistor base

Tags: capacitor

I'm investigating problem with electric wheelchair battery charger. Battery connector is connected to relay, which is controlled by circuit pasted below. PIC MCU GPIO output goes through diode and capacitor to transistor base. I don't understand, how to keep relay turned on, since capacitor blocks DC. When I just put 5V there, relay stays on for fraction of second and then disconnects. I couldn't find any other signal controlling relay coil.

What could be the purpose of such circuit? Is there a way how to keep relay turned on?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXbIcT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Send a repeating pulse to activate relay. > 50Hz

Comment: I used higher frequency, but it worked. Thanks

Comment: It is surprising that relay coil does not have a flyback diode in parallel with it.

Comment: It does have flyback diode, I just didn't draw it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> *What could be the purpose of such circuit? Is there a way how to keep
> relay turned on?*

It's a sort of safety feature should the MCU go wrong and put-out a continuous logic high signal. The MCU has to be working so that it can produce a series of pulses to keep the relay operated. This keeps the relay turned on and that's how you should do it. Maybe use a 555 timer or some other form of astable/oscillator circuit.